# Interesting equation $P(x)=Q(y)$, with infinite integer solutions $(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials

> An equation $P(x)=Q(y)$ is called **Interesting** if $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials with degree at least one and integer coefficients and the equation has an infinite number of answers in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.
>
> An interesting equation $P(x)=Q(y)$ **yields in** interesting equation $F(x)=G(y)$ if there exists polynomial $R(x) \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ such that $F(x) \equiv R(P(x))$ and $G(x) \equiv R(Q(x))$.
>
> **a.** Suppose that $S$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N} \times
>     \mathbb{N}$. $S$ is an **answer** of interesting equation
>       $P(x)=Q(y)$ if each element of $S$ is an answer of this equation. 
>       Prove that for each $S$ there's an interesting equation
>       $P_0(x)=Q_0(y)$ such that if there exists any interesting equation
>       that $S$ is an answer of it, $P_0(x)=Q_0(y)$ yields in that
>       equation.
>
> **b.** Define the **degree** of an interesting equation $P(x)=Q(y)$ by
>       $max\{deg(P),deg(Q)\}$. An interesting equation is called **primary** if 
>       there's no other interesting equation with lower degree that yields in it. 
>       Prove that if $P(x)=Q(y)$ is a primary interesting equation and $P$ and $Q$ 
>       are monic then $gcd(deg(P),deg(Q))=1$.

The two problems are originated from the 2013 Iranian Math Olympiad, 3rd Round. I have not been able to solve any of the problems, and I cannot find the solutions elsewhere.

Here is my current sketch for problem **a.** :

**Step 1:** Suppose that $S$ is an answer of infinitely many interesting equations, including the two interesting equations $P(x)=Q(y)$ and $F(x)=G(y)$.

**Lemma 1.1:** Without loss of generality assume that the leading coefficients of $P$ and $F$ are positive integers. Then the leading coefficients of $Q$ and $G$ must also be positive integers.

- If not, then $\lim Q(y) = - \infty$, $\lim P(x) = + \infty$, so the equation has a finite number of answers in $\mathbb{N} \times   
     \mathbb{N}$, a contradiction.

**Lemma 1.2:** Without loss of generality assume that $deg(P) \leq deg(Q)$. Then $deg(F)$ must be less than or equal to $deg(G)$.

- Since $deg(P) \leq deg(Q)$, there are infinite answers $(x, y)$ in $S$, such that $x < y$. Therefore, since $F(x)=G(y)$ has infinite solutions $(x, y)$ in $S$, $deg(F)$ must be less than or equal to $deg(G)$

**Lemma 1.3:** Without loss of generality assume that $deg(P) \leq deg(Q)$ and  $deg(P) \leq deg(F)$. Then  $deg(P) < deg(F)$ if and    only if $deg(Q) < deg(G)$. Moreover $deg(P) = deg(F)$ if and only if    $deg(Q) = deg(G)$.

- Consider the case in which $deg(P) < deg(F)$.
- If $deg(Q) > deg(G) \geq deg(F) > deg(P)$ then the leading coefficient of $F-P$ is positive, while the leading coefficient of $G-Q$ is negative. This contradicts **Lemma 1.1** (Note that $S$ is also an answer of the interesting equation $F(x)-P(x)=G(y)-Q(y)$).
- If $deg(Q) = deg(G)$, then the leading coefficient of $F-aP$ is positive, while the leading coefficient of $G-aQ$ is negative ($a$ is the positive integer such that the leading coefficient of $aQ$ is greater than $G$'s). This also contradicts **Lemma 1.1** (Note that $S$ is an answer of the interesting equation $F(x)-aP(x)=G(y)-aQ(y)$).
- Therefore $deg(P) < deg(F)$ if and only if $deg(Q) < deg(G)$.
- With arguments similar to the above, it can be proven that $deg(P) = 
     deg(F)$ if and only if $deg(Q) = deg(G)$.

**Lemma 1.4:** $\frac{deg(P)}{deg(Q)}=\frac{deg(F)}{deg(G)}$, regardless of whether $deg(P)$ is less than $deg(Q)$, $deg(F)$ or not.

- Note that $S$ is the answer of the interesting equations $P^{deg(F)}(x)=Q^{deg(F)}(y)$ and $F^{deg(P)}(x)=G^{deg(P)}(y)$.
- Thus according to **Lemma 1.3** , $deg(Q^{deg(F)}) =
     deg(G^{deg(P)})$; in other words, $deg(Q) \times deg(F) = deg(P)
     \times deg(G)$, or $\frac{deg(P)}{deg(Q)}=\frac{deg(F)}{deg(G)}$.

**Step 2:** **Lemma 2:** Assume that $P(x)=Q(y)$ is the equation with the smallest degree, of all equations of which $S$ is the answer. Then $deg(P)|deg(F)$ and $deg(Q)|deg(G)$

- I wasn't able to prove **Lemma 2**. But if problem **b.** is proven,
  then **Lemma 2** might be able to be proven with the similar techniques.

**Step 3:** **Lemma 3:** If $deg(P)|deg(F)$ and $deg(Q)|deg(G)$, then $P(x)=Q(y)$ yields in the equation $F(x)=G(y)$ (With definition of $P,Q,F,G$ similar to **Step 1** and **2**).

- Let $k = \frac{deg(F)}{deg(P)} = \frac{deg(G)}{deg(Q)} $. Let $p,q,f,g$ be the leading coefficient of $P,Q,F,G$ respectively, and without loss of generality assume that $gcd(p,q)=gcd(f,g)=1$. It can be seen that ${f} \times P^k(x)={f}\times Q^k(y)$ and ${p^k} \times F(x)={p^k}\times G(y)$ are interesting equations, and according to **Lemma 1.3**, it can be proven that $f = p^k, g = q^k$. Therefore $$U(x) = {f} \times P^k(x) - {p^k} \times F(x) = {f}\times Q^k(y) - {p^k}\times G(y) = V(y)$$ is an interesting equation, with $deg(U) < deg(F)$ and $deg(V) < deg(G)$. From **Lemma 2**, it can be seen that 
  $deg(P)|deg(U)$ and $deg(Q)|deg(V)$.
- Continuing the process similar to the above by changing $F$ with $U$, $G$
  with $V$, with the fact that $S$ is also the answer of $U(x)=V(y)$, it can be achieved that $P(x)=Q(y)$ yields in $F(x)=G(y)$, and problem **a.** is solved.

To conclude, here are my questions:

> How can I solve the two original problems ?
>
> Can I solve them using my ideas above ?
>
> If a solution or the question has been posted, please let me know.

Any suggestions, answers, comments, edits will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a full solution for a.

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $P(x)=Q(y)$ be an interesting equation for which $S$ is an answer.

Write $S=\{(x_i,y_i)|i \geq 1\}$ any enumeration.

So we have $P(x_i)=Q(y_i)$. Assume $y_{\varphi(i)}$ is constant: then $P(x_{\varphi(i)})$ is constant, so since $x_{\varphi(i)}$ is injective, $P$ is constant, a contradiction.

So (similarly) $x_i$ and $y_i$ both go to infinity.

Let then $p$ be the degree of $P$ ($\alpha$ the dominant coefficient), $q$ be the degree of $Q$ ($\beta$ the dominant coefficient), then $\frac{P(x_i)}{\alpha x_i^p}$ and $\frac{Q(y_i)}{\beta y_i^q}$ go to $1$ as $i$ goes to infinity.

Therefore, $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{x_i^p}{y_i^q}$ goes to $1$ as $i$ goes to infinity.

This shows that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same sign, and that $p/q$, $(|\alpha|/|\beta|)^{1/q}$ have to be constants (say, $r$ and $\delta$), depending only on $S$ (and more precisely on any infinite subset of $S$)

So assume now that $P(x)=Q(y)$ is an interesting equation with answer any cofinite subset of $S$ such that the degree of $Q$ is minimal.

Let $P_1(x)=Q_1(y)$ be an interesting equation with answer a cofinite subset of $S$ such that $P(x)=Q(y)$ does not yield to it, such that $Q_1$ has minimal degree (and among these, such that $|\alpha|+|\beta|$ is minimal).

If $Q_1$ and $Q$ have the same degree, then so do $P_1$ and $P$, and by the above (with the same notations) $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and $(\alpha,\beta)$ are proportional: let $c,c_1$ be nonzero integers such that $c_1\alpha_1=c\alpha$ (same for $\beta$).

Then $(cP-c_1P_1,cQ-c_1Q_1)$ has a cofinite subset of $S$ as an answer, and a lower degree, so it cannot be interesting and thus the polynomials are constants, so $(P,Q)$ yields in $(P_1,Q_1)$, a contradiction.

So $Q_1$ has a higher degree than $Q$. Let us write Euclidean divisions in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, $P_1=A_1P+A_2$, $Q_1=B_1Q+B_2$. Up to multiplication by an integer constant, we may assume that all the polynomials have integer coefficients.

So we have on a cofinite subset of $S$, $(A_1(x_i)-B_1(y_i))P(x_i)=A_2(x_i)-B_2(y_i)$.

Since $A_2,B_2$ have lower degrees than $P,Q$, $A_2(x_i)$ and $B_2(y_i)$ are negligible before $P(x_i)=Q(y_i)$. So their difference is negligible before $(A_1(x_i)-B_1(y_i))P(x_i)$ (on the subset of $i$ such that $A_1(x_i) \neq B_1(y_i)$).

As a conclusion, on a cofinite subset of $S$, $A_1(x_i)=B_1(y_i)$ and thus $A_2(x_i)=B_2(y_i)$. By minimality of $P,Q$, $A_2$ and $B_2$ are constants, and $A_1,B_1$ (by mininality of $P_1,Q_1$) are yielded in by $P,Q$. We get a contradiction.